# How i can "charge" a array from a while

Tags: php, arrays

I try to make a array with values from 2 column but array contain only the last entry. It is logical, but i'm stuck.

```
$dbclass = new DB_MSSQL;
$dbclass->query("Select *  from MyTable");
while($dbclass->next_record()) {
$dbclassarray = array ($dbclass->f('MyColumn1') => ''.$dbclass->f('MyColumn2').'',);}


/* $dbclass->f('MyColumn1') represent all dates from Column1 ,
   $dbclass->f('MyColumn2') represent all dates from Column2.*/
```

I want array to be like that:

```
$dbclassarray = array (MyColumn1 = > 'MyColumn2', MyColumn1 = > 'MyColumn2',MyColumn1 = > 'MyColumn2', ++)
```

My actual code return me variable `$dbclassarray` for each sql row.

Comment: all keys in array must be unique, otherway php has no clue what value you need based on key

Comment: oh, I've understood, change `$dbclassarray = array...` to `$dbclassarray[$dbclass->f('MyColumn1')] = $dbclass->f('MyColumn2');`

Comment: Yes it work, thank you very much Lashane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using Key=>value for each item in the array, you must use a different name for each Key.

I strongly suggest to not use key=>value in this case, as you only need values in the array and reference them using the index pointer (position numbers), Ex. 0,1,2,3.

This link may help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php